# Select coprimes from list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Given

```
t2 = {{1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 
2}, {3, 3}};
```

I can get coprime pairs by

```
Pick[#, CoprimeQ @@@ #] &@t2
```

or by

```
Select[t2, CoprimeQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &]
```

But I want to use `Select` in a more elegant way. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need it to be 'elegant'? What you have is already fast and readable. I would write `Select[t2, CoprimeQ@@#&]` if I wanted to be more terse.

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning and try to understand using pure functions.

Comment: Or a non-pure function method:  Pick[t2, CoprimeQ @@@ t2]

Comment: Or `Pick[#,CoprimeQ@@Transpose@#]&[t2]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Select[Apply @ CoprimeQ] @ t2
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
> ```

Also

```
Select[CoprimeQ @@ # &] @ t2
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
> ```